# HTML date input initial value

Tags: angular

Trying to incorporate a date picker into my angular app.  My issue is that when it initially loads the input field displays '01/01/2018' regardless of what value the model holds.  After I select a date, both the input display and the model are updated correctly.  How do I go about initializing the datepicker/input?

```
<input type="date" name="Date" class="form-control" id="Date" [ngModel]="stat.dpndcyDt | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="stat.dpndcyDt=$event" [value]="stat.dpndcyDt | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" />
```

dpndcyDt is a Date object.  I presume this has to do with going from string>Date and vice versa but I'm not sure what the fix is.

*edit added image
[image: date picker not showing correct date on load]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the cause was having the date inputs in a loop and using the same id for all of them.  They were all showing the initial date for the last field to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this solution

add initial value of `ngModel` in ts file of `stat.dpndcyDt`

```
stat={
        dpndcyDt:new Date() 
}
```

Comment: I added an image to clarify.  The date on top is just the {{stat.dpndcyDt}}
The bottom is the date picker bound to stat.dpndcyDt on the initial load.